# Unit testing a TFS 2010 process workflow

Tags: unit-testing, workflow

I'm trying to load a TFS 2010 workflow into a unit test. This workflow has a number of custom workflow activities used to customize our build process because there's no previously existing functionality out there for what we need to do that we can find. I want to shorten the process of testing out this customized workflow as much as possible, hence the unit testing. Has anybody had any experience with this ? Does anybody know how to load a TFS workflow manually in code ?

Answer (score 1):

I put the core functionalities of the workflow to classes, use them in the activities and test them separately.

After done that I test the workflow itself with the [WorkFlowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx).

Additionally I do some integration tests for the team build itself.

Some ressources can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd179724.aspx), [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) and [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/06/dependency-injection-with-windows-workflow-foundation-4-introduction/)